# Unable to Understand a javaScript code which I got from a tutorial website

Tags: javascript

I was just following a tutorial from a website for JavaScript. I am facing a problem in understanding a function.

Actually, It was for rotating a word. Where the last word gets removed and added at the first place or you can say at 0 index place.

Here below I am pasting the code for that function, where in JavaScript code section I am unable to understand `setInterval` function and why there is written the line `textNode.data = text;`

which is opposite of `var text = textNode.data;` in `animate_string()`

```js
function animate_string(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById("target");
  var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
  var text = textNode.data;
  setInterval(function() {
    text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    textNode.data = text;
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript basic animation</title>
</head>
<body onload="animate_string('target')">
  <pre id="target">w3resource </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's explain the JavaScript line by line:

```
function animate_string(id){
  // Get element #target
  var element = document.getElementById("target");

  // Get the first node of #target,
  // which is the "w3resource " text node
  var textNode = element.childNodes[0];

  // Cache the data of the first node of #target,
  // which is the "w3resource " string
  var text = textNode.data;

  // setInterval is a global function that runs a function repeatedly, with interval of n secodns.
  // In this case, the interval is 100 milliseconds.
  setInterval(function ()  {

    // text[text.length - 1]: Gets the last character of `text`
    // text.substring(...)  : Extracts all characters of `text`, except the last character
    // Concat the last character to the start of the remaining characters.
    // Assign the new value to `text`.
    text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);

    // Reassign the new `text` to the data of the text node,
    // thus updating the displayed text
    textNode.data = text;

  }, 100);
}
```

To demonstrate the result of the function passed to `setInterval`:

```
/* Loop: result */
 0:  w3resource
 1: e w3resourc
 2: ce w3resour
 3: rce w3resou
 4: urce w3reso
 5: ource w3res
 6: source w3re
 7: esource w3r
 8: resource w3
 9: 3resource w
10: w3resource
```

[More about setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Thank you, bro, for your time
you helped me a lot by line to line explanation.
you solved my all queries.

Comment: @KAPILSHARMA glad it helped. Appreciate if you can mark it as answer ;)

Comment: can't we remove the line  **var textNode = element.childNodes[0];** and instead
add the .innerhtml in **var element = document.getElementById("target");**

Comment: Yes you can remove that line but not adding .innerHTML, it will break the code of this structure. You should do text = element.innerText instead.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval invokes your function with period specified by second parameter. In you case

```
function ()
{
text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
textNode.data = text;
}
```

will execute every 100 milliseconds.
Here:

```
var text = textNode.data;
```

we store text value from textNode for future calculation and here

```
textNode.data = text;
```

we overwrite textNode's text value with new one. Because of we overwrite it in periodically running function therefore user see animated text.

Comment: why it is necessary to write the line
     var textNode = element.childNodes[0];

Comment: really that was no strong reason to set textNode value. it could be done this way:
`function animate_string(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById("target");
  var text = element.childNodes[0].data;
  setInterval(function() {
    text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    element.childNodes[0].data = text;
  }, 100);
}`